# Video reference not being destroyed in close modal react

Tags: reactjs

In react, I have a page which lists a bunch of videos which all have play click event attached. Only one video should be played at a time and so there is a modal popup that plays the video in question (using ReactPlayer).

When I close the modal, and click on play another video the video does play, but when I repeat this more than 3 times, the page hangs and memory increases so it seems the previous video reference is not being destroyed and so the page hangs.
What's the best way to clean up the reference so that upon close of the modal the reference is destroyed completely?
Code is below

```
class VidDisplay extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
currvid: "",
vidref: null,
vidplaying =false,
};
```

}

```
HandlePlayVidClick = (item) => {
this.setState({ currvid: item, vidref: React.createRef() });
  };


render ()
   const {
vidplaying,
      currvid,
      vidref,
    } = this.state;
{
const vidModal = document.getElementById("vidModal");
const handleHidden = () => {
  this.setState({ vidplaying: false });
};
const handleShow = () => {
  this.setState({ vidplaying: true });
};

if (vidModal) {
  vidModal.addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", handleHidden);
}

if (vidModal) {
  vidModal.addEventListener("show.bs.modal", handleShow);
}

return (
// logic that attaches video link to each individual video
 {val?.data.length ? (
                      val?.data.map((elm, i) => (
<div>
<Link
                            href="#"
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#vidModal"
                            data-bs-videolink={elm.full_video}
                            onClick={() =>
                              this.HandlePlayVidClick(elm.full_video)
                            }
                          >
                            preview
                          </Link>
</div>
))

// modal code
<div className="modal fade profile-modal" id="vidModal">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            ></button>
          </div>
          {vidplaying && (
            <div className="modal-body">
              <ReactPlayer
                url={`${process.env.REACT_APP_VIDEO_URL}${currvid}`}
                ref={vidref}
                className="react-player"
                playsinline={true}
                muted={true}
                controls={true}
                playing={vidplaying}
                width={"100%"}
                
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding in an id into the modal declaration and ensuring it is unique when a different video is played and therefore previous one is destroyed upon rerender